# Regex ignore white space

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have following piece of code:

```
string.replace(",Target_String", ""));
```

The thing is that comma `,` can happen before and after the `Target_String` and sometimes there can be space between comma and `Target_String`.

I want to avoid code such as having four different `replace` methods like:

```
string.replace(",Target_String", ""));
string.replace(", Target_String", ""));
string.replace("Target_String,", ""));
string.replace("Target_String ,", ""));
```

But I don't know how can I achive above functionality with regular expression.

Edit: comma can be found only at the end or the beggining - never on the both sides of the `target_string`

Comment: Should comma on both sides `",Target_String,"` be considered a match or not?

Comment: You can try with [ ]?[,]?[ ]?(Target_String)[ ]?[,]?[ ]? (if could) be more than one replace ? with + I suggest you to use site like [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output) to test and learn about regex

Comment: Use: `string = string.replaceAll(",?\\h*Target_String\\h*,?", "");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex `replaceAll`:

```
string = string.replaceAll(",?\\h*Target_String\\h*,?", "");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mK0lYv/1)

**Explanation:**

- `,?\\h`: Match optional comma followed by 0 or more horizontal spaces
- `Target_String`: Match literal text `Target_String`
- `\\h*,?`: Match 0 or more horizontal spaces followed by an optional comma

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replaceAll` as

```
string.replaceAll(",\\s*Target_String\\s*,","");
```

`\\s*` match zero or more space characters

if there's only one possibility of space then you can use `?` to represent a possible character occurrence.

```
    string.replaceAll(",\\s?Target_String\\s?,","");
```

or use

```
    string.replaceAll("[, ]*Target_String[, ]*","");
```

`[, ]*`: match zero or more occurrences of `,` and space character

Comment: can I combine zero or more occurences of `,` with zero or more occurences of `space`?
`string.replaceAll("[,\\s? ]*Target_String[,\\s? ]*","");`

Comment: @Lenny yes, though `?` inside `[]` will be used as a character though you can use `[, ]*` for zero or more occurrences of comma and space characters, `[, ]*`  is same as `[,\\s]*` or better `[,\\h]*` where `\\h` is only horizontal space.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `string.replace(",\\s*Target_String\\s*", ""));`

[Demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydvmemar)

Answer (score 0):

`string.replace("\\s*,?\\s*Target_String\\s*,?\\s*", ""));`

Answer (score 0):

*would this not be sufficient?*
all commas would then be set uniformly in the line

```
"Target_String,   blah , Target_String  ,Target_String ,".replaceAll( "\\h*,\\h*", "," ) );
```

gets: `Target_String,blah,Target_String,Target_String,`